# Viewing "unformatted" disk

Tags: linux, mount, dd

I have an SD card without obvious file system. I'm seeing if the data on there (largely) follows a particular file system's convention. In linux, I ran `sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=SDcard.bin`

`fdisk SDcard.bin` gives

> Disk SDcard.bin: 3.7GiB, 3965190144 bytes, 7744512 sectors
>   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal):512 / 512 bytes

doing `sudo mount -o ro,loop SDcard.bin /mnt/SD`
results in a error:

> mount: wrong fs type, bad option bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

trying `sudo losetup --partscan --find --show SDcard.bin`
responds with "/dev/loop0"

but I can't `fsck /dev/loop0` or `mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/SD`, even trying several options for `-t`

I did an `xxd SDcard.bin SDcard.hex` and I see, in the middle of the file (e.g. around address 00400040) `a2b2NO NAME    FAT32  [00].` (spacing sic, [00] = no data) and some readable text earlier than that in several places.

Should I try to mount as Fat32 with offsets, e.g. `losetup --offset 00400040 /dev/loop0 SDCard.bin`*

*where I translate 00400040 from hex to dec first

Comment: You didn't say where the SD card is from or what you'd expect it to contain. Obviously it neither starts with a partition table, nor with one of the usual file systems. Try [binwalk](http://binwalk.org/) on it and see if it comes up with anything useful.

Comment: thanks @dirkt - that shows an early-addressed mcrypt-encrypted data, with an 8bit keymode.  Does that mean a single byte is the "password"? The algorithm is DES and the mode CBC.  How would I "intelligently brute-force" this? Or will I have to decrypt essentially 4GB using multiple keys and look for english strings or common headers/signatures manually? Should I throw away the parts of the file that has stretches of >16 (or 100...) null characters?

Comment: Ask that at [reverseengineering](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/). Also note that binwalk sometimes produces false positives; if you don't have reason to assume that the contents of the SD card *are* encrypted (because of where it came from, which you didn't mention), this could be possibly one. The "NO NAME  FAT32" bit is clearly not encrypted, and unless it's part of the mcrypt-header, I don't see how it fits.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try some tools like PhotoRec and Testdisk to try find files in the broken filesystem. I doubt anybody encrypting this would be using single byte password. Would ne funny. And as @dirkt said, you see plaintext in the middle anyway.

Check some article about using the tools:
https://www.linux.com/learn/get-your-data-back-linux-based-data-recovery-tools

Comment: Do you think the OP waited this long?

Comment: @SolarMike Future users with similar problem *may* appear. Any sane answer is for them.

Comment: in my case, I concluded that it was a false-positive, and there wasn't any encrypted data.  As I recall, there was plenty of other handy info in this (or another card's) binwalk/hexdump - an unencrypted Sqlite DB.  Kamil is correct: someone else may find this help helpful, assuming it comes up in a search;)

Comment: I did not ask about future users... but that may be relevant for future users if sd cards stand the test of time...

Comment: @SolarMike, it can be useful to anybody that wants to retrieve data from broken media. You inspired me to write a long answer (probably a pathetic one for that matter). If you like you can find it at: http://rboci.blogspot.bg/2017/12/why-am-i-necromancer.html

Comment: So, my corpse has been exhumed?